# Update Collection View from View Controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have this in my `storyboard`.

**ViewController -> Tableview -> Custom cell**

the custom cell has inside a collection view.

Inside my `ViewController` i have some filter buttons that i want to filter the array data of the collection view and reload it also.

So I tried to make a delegate method with the following code

```
protocol ReloadTheDataDelegate: class {
    func reloadTheCV()
}


class NearMeViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: ReloadTheDataDelegate?

@IBAction func anAction(_sender : AnyObject){

requests.weekendEventData.sort() { $0.realDate < $1.realDate }
delegate?.reloadTheCV()

}

}


class WeekendTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, ReloadTheDataDelegate  {

@IBOutlet public weak var weekendCV: UICollectionView!

func reloadTheCV() {
        print("done")  //never printed
        weekendCV.reloadData()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()


        if let myViewController = parentViewController as? NearMeViewController {
            myViewController.delegate = self
        }

        weekendCV.register(UINib(nibName: "WeekendCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil),
                           forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "phoneweekendcell")

        weekendCV.delegate = self
        weekendCV.dataSource = self
    }
}
```

And the extension that i take the ViewController

```
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Could anyone explain why the function `reloadTheCV()` is never called ?

Comment: I'm quite confused here. Why are you having a collection view inside a table view cell? And also, when you say `ViewController -> Tableview -> Custom cell`, you mean they are on top of each other, right? Not connected by segue?

Comment: @FangmingNing Its something like a netflix app... and yes its one top of the other

Comment: Ok. Then why you have a `UICollectionView` inside your cell? Where are your filter buttons? I think what you need is just filter and reload the table view when filter button is clicked, right?

Comment: @FangmingNing "Why are you having a collection view inside a table view cell?" - that is actually not uncommon, one case would be that each table row is a separate category of content, with only one row in collection view, scrollable to the sides. The collection views are inside table rows so they can be scrollable independently. Such layout is pretty common in i.e. VOD apps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NearMeViewController` delegate (`ReloadTheDataDelegate` ) is `nil`. Due to that its not printing. You didn't set the `delegate` and this approach is too complex also.

So, Instead of approaching with `protocol` concept. Simply you can reload the cell's collection view with the following manner.

Add the following function on your `NearMeViewController`. And call whenever you need reload the collection view.

```
func reloadCellCV() {
        for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
            if let cell = cell as? WeekendTableViewCell {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.weekendCV.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeap its working.. although it would be great if i found out why the delegate is nil !

Comment: You have to set the cell object to your `NearMeViewController` delegate while creating a cell. And If you have multiple cells this approach will not work. Because one cell object will replace another cell object.

Comment: Thanks @SubramanianP After spending countless hours, I got to this solution.